# Call other Webpack loaders from within a loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I am writing a Pug dependency loader.  Basically it will just output an identical Pug file, except that `require()` calls will be replaced with a path to the file they are requiring.  Obviously, therefore, I need to take that path and hand it off to the Webpack loader chain so that it will be handled in whatever way is appropriate, e.g. by using `file-loader` to copy an image file to its appropriate location.

Everything's working except for this part.  I can't figure out how to pass the path to Webpack to be loaded.  To be clear, I want the same sort of thing to happen as when you `require()` a file in your Webpack entry file - Webpack should take the path, run it through the list of possible loaders, and handle it appropriately.

I have tried just using a `require()` call, I've tried `this.resolve()` and `this.loadModule()` but none have worked.  Since `this.resolve()` accepts a context as its first argument, I have carefully given it the appropriate context of my `/src` folder.  The image is at `/src/images/image.jpeg`, and yet it actually gives an error that it cannot resolve that path, even though it is correct, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to make this work.

Comment: I got it working with `this.loadModule()` but I need a way to change contextual root, similar to how you can do with `this.resolve()`, so that it will look for the files in the right folder.  I could program it manually but then it would only work for my specific setup that I have right now.